# The arrow, page up and down keys cause screenshots

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, screenshot

Every time I attempt to scroll through web pages with the arrow keys or insert, home, end, page up or down.... my computer snaps a screenshot. is there a system setting or fix to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Keyboard Shortcuts:

Go into System Settings
then, select Keyboard
Choose "Shortcuts," and check under "Screenshots"

Also, what version of Ubuntu are you in, and what browser are you running?  That may have something to do with it, and could prove useful in diagnosing the problem (maybe a browser-specific shortcut, or an add-on plugin running)